# How to use function inside Javascript file using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I start to develop a website using NodeJS and Express. 
This website is about a Cinema and I have to develop a form which allows users to add a movie in database with informations like a list of actors. 
I write a simple JS script to add an input to enter a new actor and I call this function addActor() in a script called dynamic.js. Here is my code :

```
console.log("Launching dynamic.js !")

function addActor(){
    var txtNewInputBox = document.createElement('div');
    txtNewInputBox.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='newInputBox'>";
    document.getElementById("actorsList").appendChild(txtNewInputBox);
}
```

Dynamic.js is stored in js repository so inside my app.js file I add the line :

```
app.use("/js", express.static("js"));
```

Of course I add this line in my  file and I also add the button :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dynamic.js"></script>

//.... some code ....//

<input type="button" name="addActor" value="ajouter" onclick="addActor()">
```

Here is the problem, when I click on the button, it returns "TypeError: addActor is not a function" but it prints "Launching dynamic.js !" so I don't know how to use my function addActor(). (If I called directly my function in web console it works so I don't understand)

If you have a solution, I will be glad to hear it ! Thanks ;)

Comment: You should include some HTML code also, also look for any error in console. I think line with `document.getElementById("actorsList")` is getting any HTML element.

Comment: I give you all my HTML code necessary and there is no problem with my function because when I call it directly in web console it works fine, my problem concerns the how can I use this function because my JS file is executed, my function works in the web console but it still doesn't work inside my HTML page like if it doesn't import my JS file.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can create a demo for it using Codepen or Fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the problem. It's because I called my button "addActor" so it didn't distinguished my JS function and my HTML button.

```
<input type="button" name="addActor" value="ajouter" onclick="addActor()">
```

name="addActor" was the problem, now it works ! Thanks for helping ;)